In my C# code, when I do Console.WriteLine("♥"); it doesn't show up on the console
This is my code:
using System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335;

Random random = new Random();

List<string> deck = new List<string>()
{
    //club
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│A        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        A│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│2        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        2│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│3        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        3│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│4        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        4│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│5        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        5│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│6        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        6│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│7        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        7│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│8        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        8│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│9        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        9│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│10       │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│       10│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│J        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        J│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│Q        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        Q│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│K        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♣    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        K│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    //diamonds
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│A        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        A│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│2        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        2│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│3        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        3│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│4        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        4│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│5        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        5│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│6        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        6│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│7        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        7│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│8        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        8│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│9        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        9│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│10       │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│       10│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│J        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        J│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│Q        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        Q│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│K        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♦    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        K│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    //spades
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│A        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│             │\r\n│        A│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│2        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        2│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│3        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        3│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│4        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        4│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│5        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        5│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│6        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        6│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│7        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        7│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│8        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        8│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│9        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        9│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│10       │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│       10│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│J        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        J│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│Q        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        Q│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│K        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♠    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        K│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    //hearts
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│A        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│             │\r\n│        A│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│2        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        2│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│3        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        3│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│4        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        4│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│5        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        5│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│6        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        6│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│7        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        7│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│8        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        8│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│9        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        9│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│10       │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│       10│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│J        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        J│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│Q        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│        Q│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
    "┌─────────┐\r\n│K        │\r\n│         │\r\n│         │\r\n│    ♥    │\r\n│         │\r\n│                 │\r\n│        K│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n",
};

    List<int> cardValues = new List<int>()
        {
        //clubs
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
        //diamonds
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
        //spades
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
        //hearts
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
    };

    int cardnumber;
    int cardnumber1;
    int cardnumber2;
    int cardnumber3;

    int hit;

    int dealerHit;
    int dealerValue;

    double usermoney = 50;
    int cardValue = 0;
    double userBet = 0;
    string answer = "";
    string answer1 = "";

    int value = 0;
    string dealerCard =     "┌─────────┐\r\n│░░░░░░░░░│\r\n│░░░░░░░░░│\r\n│░░░░░░░░░│\r\n│░░░░░░░░░│\r\n│░░░░░░░░░│\r\n│░░░░░░░░    ░│\r\n│░░░░░░░░░│\r\n└─────────┘\r\n";

    Console.WriteLine("welcome to \n\r\noooooooooo.  oooo                      oooo           oooo                         oooo        \r\n`888'   `Y8b `888                      `888           `888                     `888            \r\n 888     888  888   .oooo.    .ooooo.   888  oooo      888  .oooo.    .ooooo.   888  oooo  \r\n     888oooo888'  888  `P  )88b  d88' `\"Y8  888 .8P'       888 `P  )88b  d88' `\"Y8  888 .8P'   \r\n 888        `88b  888   .oP\"888  888        888888.        888  .oP\"888  888        888888.    \r\n 888        .88P  888  d8(  888  888   .o8  888 `88b.      888 d8(  888  888   .o8  888 `88b.  \r\no888bood8P'      o888o `Y888\"\"8o `Y8bod8P' o888o o888o .o. 88P `Y888\"\"8o `Y8bod8P' o888o o888o \r\n                                                       `Y888P                                  \r\n                                                                                                   \r\n                                                                                                   \r\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to see the rules?");

    while (true)
    {
        answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        if (answer == "yes")
        {
            rules();
        }
        else if (answer == "no")
        {
            randomCardDraw();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter yes or no");
        }
    }

    void rules()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nGoal: get closer to 21 than the dealer withou going over.\n\nGameplay: you will be given two cards and you must hit or stand.\nHit: when you hit you will be given another card that will add on to your other two to bring your value closer to 21.\nStand: when you say stand the cards you have will be locked in and you can't get more cards.\n\nDealer: the dealer must stand at 17 or above.\n\nTie: if you and the dealers cards add up to the same value the you will get your bet                 back without losing or winning any money.\n");

        Console.WriteLine("\npress ENTER to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();

        randomCardDraw();
    }

    void mainCode()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You now have ${0:00.00}", usermoney + " in your account");

            if (usermoney <= 0) { endOfGame(); }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            // playGame();
  
            Console.WriteLine("would you like to keep playing");

            answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    
            if (answer == "yes")
            {
                randomCardDraw();
            }
            else if (answer == "no")
            {
                endOfGame();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please enter yes or no");
            }
        }
    }

    randomCardDraw();

    int randomCardDraw()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("You now have ${0:00.00}", usermoney + " in your account");
        Console.WriteLine("how much would you like to bet?");

        try
        {
            userBet = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter a whole number");
            usermoney = 50;
        }

        // dealer
        // cardNumber2 = dealerCard
        Console.WriteLine("Dealer:");
        cardnumber2 = random.Next(0, deck.Count);
        cardnumber3 = random.Next(0, deck.Count);

        Console.WriteLine("the dealer drew \n" + dealerCard + "&\n" + deck[cardnumber3]);

        // player
        Console.WriteLine("You:");
        cardnumber = random.Next(0, deck.Count);
        cardnumber1 = random.Next(0, deck.Count);

        Console.WriteLine("You drew \n" + deck[cardnumber] + "&\n" + deck[cardnumber1]);

        value = cardValues[cardnumber] + cardValues[cardnumber1];
        Console.WriteLine("Those have the value of " + value);

        cardValue = cardValues[cardnumber];

        playGame();

        return cardValue;
    }

    void playGame()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to hit or stand?");
            answer1 = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (answer1 == "hit")
            {
                hit = random.Next(0, deck.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("You drew \n" + deck[hit]);
                value = value + cardValues[hit];
                Console.WriteLine("Your cards add up to " + value);

                if (value < 21)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (value == 21)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("BLACKJACK!!!!");
                    usermoney = usermoney + userBet;
 
                    mainCode();
                }
                else if (value > 21)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bust! You Lost");
                    usermoney = usermoney - userBet;
                    mainCode();
                }
            }
            else if (answer1 == "stand")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter hit or stand!");
                continue;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Lets see what the dealer had");
        Console.WriteLine("the dealer had \n" + deck[cardnumber2] + "&\n" + deck[cardnumber3]);
        dealerValue = cardValues[cardnumber2] + cardValues[cardnumber3];

        Console.WriteLine("that has a value of " + dealerValue);

        if (dealerValue < 17)
        {
            dealerHit = random.Next(0, deck.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("The dealer hit and got a \n" + deck[dealerHit]);
            dealerValue = dealerValue + cardValues[dealerHit];
            Console.WriteLine("The dealer's cards add up to " + dealerValue);
        }
        else if (dealerValue >= 17)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The dealer stands");
        }
    }
    
    void endOfGame()
    {
    }

Whenever I try to run my code the symbols don't show up on the console and I know the symbols work because they worked fine on my friend's PC.
I tried Console.WriteLine("♥"); and it didn't print out the symbol
I really need help with this because it is for a school assignment.
and it is my first post on here so sorry if it is bad

You may need to enable Unicode. Have you tried Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode; ?

As someone alreay commented, you can enable Unicode like this:
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;


A useful note: you can use Raw string literals. They allow you to include line breaks in a natural way. Example:
string s = """
    ┌─────────┐
    │A        │
    │         │
    │         │
    │    ♣    │
    │         │
    │         │
    │        A│
    └─────────┘

    """;
//  ^ white spaces to the left of the closing `"""` are not included in the string.    

